# Optional: true issue in rails v4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :item_carts, dependent: :destroy

  def total
    item_carts.map(&:sub_total).sum
  end
end
```

I am  having an issue in rails version 4.2 regarding (optional: true) property,
I just to make sure that my foreign key is optional but option has been introduced in rails 5.....
need guidance!

Comment: Please avoid adding tags that don't really relate to the question: `ruby-on-rails-3`, `rubygems` and `ruby-git`. This question is not really about any of those things.

Comment: Prior to rails 5, `belongs_to` relationships are optional *by default*. Have you tried creating a record without the foreign key? If there was an error, then what does the error say? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70362071/edit) to include this information, if applicable.

Comment: My expectation is that there is nothing you need to change, unless you upgrade to rails 5+. The only way I think this could fail is if there's extra code you haven't shown us (e.g. a presence validation), or if you have added the constraint at a database level?

Answer (score 1):

The `optional:` option (and its inverse `required:`) just determine if the assocation adds a `validates_presence_of` assocation. This is the abstraction that ActiveRecord is creating on top of your database. The only thing that changed in Rails 5 is that it defaults to `false`.

If you want to keep the behavior of Rails 4 you need to add `optional: true` to your  association. If you want to ensure that sloppy code without `optional: false` that was written in Rails 4 will actually work in Rails 5 you should explicitly set it before upgrading and run your tests.

The foreign key is actually a database level concern - it creates a constraint linking from one table to another. Assocations actually work no matter if you have a foreign key constraint or not. It just ensures referential integrity on the database level.

A "foreign key column" may be nullable or not. If the column is not nullable then creating a record will still fail even if you made the association optional.